# QuickText in notepad++ not saving code snippets!

Tags: plugins, notepad++, code-snippets

I installed notepad++ on Windows7. I installed QuickText into notepad++. I add my custom snippets into QuickText and while notepad is open, the snippets work fine. As soon as I close notepad and open it again, the snippets are gone. Has anyone else had this problem, it should be an easy fix? They are not persisting or sticking.

Anyone know how to fix this? Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, a little late to the party but please see my answer as it actually solves the quicktext issue and does not require getting a new/different plugin.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used Quicktext but it looks like it is no longer under development.

From what I can tell [FingerText](https://github.com/erinata/FingerText) is similar, and hopefully should be able to do what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

The complete answer lies in a combination of Nick's and Jrod's answers.

If you create the a Config folder in the C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\ (or C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\ if you installed it to that folder) and then place the QuickText.ini file within that folder you will notice many default "snippits" show up.

Now in order for you to save your "snippits" if you are in Windows 7 or Vista (which will save to the QuickText.ini file) you must run Notepad++ as Administrator.

As a side note the snippits save fine with in Linux if you install Notepad++ through Wine.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by administrative privileges.  You need to run notepad++ as an administrator or it will fail silently.

Answer (score 1):

You must copy QuickText.ini to folder `c:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\Config\` (I created this folder itself)

[This page](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Text-editors/Moreno-QuickText.shtml) help me

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my badly english. Your problem is in `inslall`. Correct install:

- Copy to folder `plugins` all files except one (`quicktext.ini`).
- In such directory create new folder `config`.
- Copy `quicktext.ini` into it.

After such installation snippets works correctly.

Comment: I had the same problem and can confirm that this works! Thanks!